# Leading 0 in serach box throws error (Laravel Datatable)

Tags: laravel, search, join, datatable

I have used left to join multiple tables in my controller method. It returns data as desired but when I type into search box '0' it throws an error.

Using https://datatables.yajrabox.com/ this Laravel Datatable plugin

It only happen when single zero(0) is there in search box. '00' or 't0102' works fine.

only single '0' as search value throws an error.

Happens on the demo site to
https://datatables.yajrabox.com/eloquent/row-num
try to search for 0(zero) only and it will throw back you an error.

After spending couple of hours I came to the conclusion the it is because in MySql query LIKE %0% is not adding inverted commas('') around 0(zero)
It should be LIKE '%0%' instead LIKE %0%.
Code snippet of problem

Below is my Query Builder Code

```
$surveys = DB::table('surveys as su')
    ->leftJoin('assignments as a', 'su.assignment_id', '=', 'a.id')
    ->leftJoin('rounds as r', 'a.round_id', '=', 'r.id')
    ->leftJoin('projects as p', 'r.project_id', '=', 'p.id')
    ->leftJoin('sites as s',  'a.site_id', '=', 's.id')
    ->leftJoin('fieldreps as f', 'a.fieldrep_id', '=', 'f.id')
    ->leftJoin('chains as ch','p.chain_id','=','ch.id')
    ->leftJoin('clients as c','ch.client_id','=','c.id')
    ->leftJoin('surveys_templates as t', 'su.template_id', '=', 't.id')
    ->where(function ($query) {
      $query->where('a.is_reported', '=', true)
      ->orWhere('a.is_partial', '=', true)
      ->orWhere('a.is_approved', '=', true);
    })
    //->where('su.service_code', '!=', '')
    ->select([
      'a.id as assignment_id',
      'a.fieldrep_id',
      'a.deadline_date',
      'a.is_reported',
      'a.is_partial',
      'a.is_approved',
      'c.client_logo',
      'p.id as project_id',
      'p.project_name',
      'r.id as round_id',
      'r.round_name',
      's.site_code',
      's.site_name',
      's.city',
      's.state',
      's.zipcode',
      'su.id as survey_id',
      'su.status',
      'su.service_code',
      't.template_name',
      DB::raw("CONCAT(IFNULL( DATE_FORMAT(a.schedule_date,'%e/%c/%Y'), DATE_FORMAT(r.schedule_date,'%e/%c/%Y')), ' ' , IFNULL(a.start_time, r.start_time)) as assignment_scheduled"),
      DB::raw("CONCAT(IFNULL( DATE_FORMAT(a.schedule_date,'%d %b %Y'), DATE_FORMAT(r.schedule_date,'%d %b %Y')), ' ' , IFNULL(a.start_time, r.start_time)) as assignment_scheduled_date"),
      DB::raw("CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(a.start_date,'%d %b %Y'),' ',a.start_time) as assignment_starts"),
      DB::raw('CONCAT(f.first_name," ",f.last_name) as schedule_to'),
      ]);
```

Syntax error or access violation: 1583 Incorrect parameters in the call to native function 'LOWER' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from (select a.id as assignment_id, a.fieldrep_id, a.deadline_date, a.is_reported, a.is_partial, a.is_approved, c.client_logo, p.id as project_id, p.project_name, r.id as round_id, r.round_name, s.site_code, s.site_name, s.city, s.state, s.zipcode, su.id as survey_id, su.status, su.service_code, t.template_name, CONCAT(IFNULL( DATE_FORMAT(a.schedule_date,'%e/%c/%Y'), DATE_FORMAT(r.schedule_date,'%e/%c/%Y')), ' ' , IFNULL(a.start_time, r.start_time)) as assignment_scheduled, CONCAT(IFNULL( DATE_FORMAT(a.schedule_date,'%d %b %Y'), DATE_FORMAT(r.schedule_date,'%d %b %Y')), ' ' , IFNULL(a.start_time, r.start_time)) as assignment_scheduled_date, CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(a.start_date,'%d %b %Y'),' ',a.start_time) as assignment_starts, CONCAT(f.first_name," ",f.last_name) as schedule_to from surveys as su left join assignments as a on su.assignment_id = a.id left join rounds as r on a.round_id = r.id left join projects as p on r.project_id = p.id left join sites as s on a.site_id = s.id left join fieldreps as f on a.fieldrep_id = f.id left join chains as ch on p.chain_id = ch.id left join clients as c on ch.client_id = c.id left join surveys_templates as t on su.template_id = t.id where (a.is_reported = 1 or a.is_partial = 1 or a.is_approved = 1) and (LOWER(s.site_code) LIKE %0% or LOWER(su.service_code) LIKE %0% or LOWER(p.project_name) LIKE %0% or LOWER(r.round_name) LIKE %0% or LOWER(s.city) LIKE %0% or LOWER(surveys as su.assignment_scheduled) LIKE %0% or LOWER(t.template_name) LIKE %0% or LOWER(surveys as su.schedule_to) LIKE %0%) order by lpad(s.site_code, 10, 0) desc) count_row_table)'

Comment: Can you add your query builder code?

Comment: Edited question.

Comment: You didn't include the part where you use `LIKE`

Comment: I think this causes the syntax error: `LOWER(surveys as su.assignment_scheduled)`

Comment: Its plugin functionality to add like Given a link to plugin where error came across in demo example too

Comment: Have you checked  https://datatables.yajrabox.com/eloquent/row-num this?

Comment: $datatables->filterColumn('assignment_scheduled', 'whereRaw', "CONCAT(IFNULL( DATE_FORMAT(a.schedule_date,'%d %b %Y'), DATE_FORMAT(r.schedule_date,'%d %b %Y')), ' ' , IFNULL(a.start_time, r.start_time)) like ? ", ["%$keyword%"]);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147807/discussion-between-felix-and-sr).